# !SOLVED! How can I print a table from a .json file in JavaScript using xmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

**[EDIT]
Complete and correct code @ https://repl.it/@aleemont/XMLPersone**

I need to read the JSON file and put all the informations it contains in a table. I'm trying to do so using XMLHttpRequest. My teacher gave me an example, but I wasn't able to understand it properly.
Here is the code which I wrote:

```
var ppl = new Array();

function load(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "data.txt";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
            if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                ppl = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                print();
            }
            else
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "ERROR";
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function print(){
    /*here is where i should create the table
     where to put the content of data.txt*/
}
```

This is the code my teacher gave me, but I do not understand what does theese methods do. It also uses a different JSON file, but it doesn't matter i guess.

```
function print(){
    var ncol=0;
    for (key in pc)
      ncol++;
    var tit = document.getElementsByTagName("title");
    var txt = tit[0].childNodes[0];
    var tab = document.getElementById("computer");
    tab.innerHTML="";
    var table = document.createElement("TABLE");

    var title = document.createElement("TR");
    var ele = document.createElement("TH");
    ele.colSpan = ncol;
    ele.appendChild(txt);    
    title.appendChild(ele);
    table.appendChild(title);

    var heading = document.createElement("TR");
    for (var x in pc[0])
    {
        txt = document.createTextNode(x);
        ele = document.createElement("TH");
        ele.appendChild(txt);
        heading.appendChild(ele);
    }
    table.appendChild(heading);
    for (var i in pc)
      {
          var row = document.createElement("TR");
      for (var x in pc[i])
      {
          if (x=="Storage")
               txt = document.createTextNode(storage[pc[i][x]]);
               else
                   txt = document.createTextNode(pc[i][x]);
               ele = document.createElement("TD");
        ele.appendChild(txt);
        riga.appendChild(ele);
      }
      table.appendChild(riga);
      }
      tab.appendChild(table);
  }
```

Comment: But what's the problem/question? After loading the file, you call `load()`, I think you want to call `print(persone)`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the mistakes I did when I pasted the code (I translated variables name thus making it more readble for everybody and didn't see that one)

Comment: `print()` needs to take `pc` as a parameter, then you call it `print(ppl)`

Comment: Uhm... in the example of my teacher it worked. I will post here the repl link so you can see it by yourself. Variables names are in Italian tho. https://repl.it/@aleemont/xml Just follow this link and press on "Run" at the top of the page, it will show the table as I expeted to.

Comment: @aleemont it will be better if you place your own code in the repl like you do with example above. in you task can be a lot of problems - for example file which your try to request is unreachable(server error), or file has a invalid structure(not a valid json), or something else. best practice in problem solving - split task to small parts. try to debug part which request file - use console.log(ppl) to inspect file content instead of building table with your print() function;

Comment: Of course, here you are: https://repl.it/@aleemont/XMLProject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ppl = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.statusText);

You need to be parsing the response text into JSON.
Use `ppl = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);` instead. Its the same in the repl you posted as well.

Comment: didn't notice that, due to Visual Studio's autocomplete function. Btw, my answer is, how does my teacher's one works? I can understand what the script does, bu I can't see HOW it works, I read the docs, but didn't understand that much.What is a node and what are `appendChild(var)` or `document.createTextNode(var)` used for? In the end, what are the two indexes used for in `txt = document.createTextNode(storage[pc[i][x]]);` and `txt = document.createTextNode(pc[i][x]);`

Comment: You shoul read about DOM manipulation with JS. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document). The indices are because of nested iteration. If you want to know what these indices contain, i suggest you log them to the console and see for yourself.